# Can't SSH into EC2 instance created with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am working on a very simple Terraform project. I am using windows command prompt. I only have one EC2 instance for now. This is the project structure -

```
terraform-project
|_ec2.tf
|_vars.tf
|_test-key
|_test-key.pub
|_.terraform
|_terraform.tfstate
```

The ec2.tf file is as below -

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-central-1"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "test-key"{
    key_name = "test-key"
    public_key = "${file("test-key.pub")}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2"{
    ami = "${var.ami}"
    instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
    key_name = "${aws_key_pair.test-key.key_name}"
    tags = {
        Name = "Terraform"
        Batch = "7am"

    }
}
```

The vars.tf file is as below -

```
variable "ami" {
    default = "ami-0233214e13e500f77"
}

variable "instance_type" {
    default = "t2.micro"
}
```

Terraform Apply worked successfully and I can see the instance from the AWS management console. But when I try to SSH into the instance I get permission issues-

```
ssh -i test-key ec2-user@54.xx.xxx.xxx
ssh: connect to host 54.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: Permission denied
```

The instance has default VPC and security group. All inbound and outbound traffic is allowed. 
I am working behind a company proxy. Before I started I set the proxy settings on my windows command prompt -

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.companytnet.net:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.companynet.net:port
```

SSH with verbose gives this:

```
ssh -vvv -i test-key ec2-user@54.xx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\M710583/.ssh/config
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 54.xx.xxx.xxx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 54.xx.xxx.xxx [54.xx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10013, io:00000256B95289B0
debug1: connect to address 54.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host 54.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: Permission denied
```

I able to SSH into other servers and instances but not into the one created with Terraform. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that the ssh `key_name` you use is the correct one?

Comment: @Marcin - Yes I checked on terraform console with "${aws_key_pair.test-key.key_name}" . This returns test-key which is the key name.

Comment: And the ami is for Amazon Linux 2 or similar, not Ubuntu, which has different user name?

Comment: @Marcin - Yes. Its a Linux ami. I have also tried with ubuntu ami but i still get the same problem

Comment: Can I ask why you have two keys in your folder, `test-key` and `test-key.pub`?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the verbose output of the SSH command with `ssh -vvv -i test-key ...` please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - SSH with verbose added to question

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need a security group allowing ssh

Comment: @HelderSepulveda - I am using default. So that should allow all traffic right ?

Comment: apparently not... can you try adding an allow all: https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/blob/master/TerraForm/sg.tf then on your instance code add `vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.allow_all.id}"]` just as a test

Comment: I have some examples that I've used in the past in that same repo: https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/blob/master/TerraForm/ec2_alpine.tf https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/blob/master/TerraForm/ec2_amzn.tf
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/blob/master/TerraForm/ec2_ubuntu.tf

Comment: This doesn't look like networking error, in this case you would've gotten "timed out" and such. Make sure that SSH server is running on the instance in the first place, it can happen that ssh daemon config is borked and server can't start.

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha - SSH is running in the windows system I am working on. But I just checked that there is  no ssh_config file in C:/ProgramData/ssh/. Could that be the reason?

Comment: No, server should run on AWS instance. You can use SSM shell access to get into instance, heck, you might even ditch SSH for it if you only use it to get into instance. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-session-manager/

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a proper security group. Something like:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
  egress = [
    {
      cidr_blocks      = [ "0.0.0.0/0", ]
      description      = ""
      from_port        = 0
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
      prefix_list_ids  = []
      protocol         = "-1"
      security_groups  = []
      self             = false
      to_port          = 0
    }
  ]
 ingress                = [
   {
     cidr_blocks      = [ "0.0.0.0/0", ]
     description      = ""
     from_port        = 22
     ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
     prefix_list_ids  = []
     protocol         = "tcp"
     security_groups  = []
     self             = false
     to_port          = 22
  }
  ]
}


resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2"{
    ami = "${var.ami}"
    instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
    key_name = "${aws_key_pair.test-key.key_name}"
    tags = {
        Name = "Terraform"
        Batch = "7am"

    }
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main.id]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding the `vpc_security_group_ids = "${aws_security_group.main-sg.id}"` to your EC2 resource block.

This attribute associates your VPC with the security group which you are referencing; [read more about it here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#vpc_security_group_ids).